# What is Patti's nickname?

Tags: yumekui-merry

It seems like all Dream Demons have a nickname in quotation:

- "Chaser" John Doe
- "Garden" Engi Threepiece
- "Pharos" Hercules

(Not sure about Merry's or Mystletainn's though I suspect Merry's last-name, Nightmare, could be in quotation)

Earlier in the series Engi talks about her sister Patti who was drawn to the human world by "Pharos" Hercules lighthouse and suspected to have been killed by Mystletainn. However, I am wondering what Patti's nickname is? Since they're sisters is it the same or related to Engi's?

Comment: You mean like their *sobriquet*? Patti's last name, like Engi's is "Threepiece." "Nightmare" is Merry's last name.

Comment: @ʞɹɐzǝɹ yeh, whatever they call the part that's in quotation as per my examples (google says it's a nickname however i don't remember Merry or Yui ever calling Engi "Guarden" regular like a nickname). since Patti and Engi are sisters i know Patti's lastname would be Threepiece but i'm curious if she also has "Garden" in her name or if it's similarly themed

Comment: Mystletainn's is 樹海(フォレスト),"Forest." Merry's is probably 夢喰い (Dream Eater).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [various](http://dic.pixiv.net/a/%E3%83%91%E3%83%86%E3%82%A3%E3%83%BB%E3%82%B9%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%83%94%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9) [sources](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%A4%A2%E5%96%B0%E3%81%84%E3%83%A1%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC#.E3.81.9D.E3.81.AE.E4.BB.96.E3.81.AE.E5.A4.A2.E9.AD.94), she shares the same sobriquet as her sister, 双月花（ガーデン）"Garden." The name reflects the duality of the two sisters.